# Checking time left from a field in database

Tags: php

I've got this filed in database stored as type DATETIME.
Consider the value for it: *2017-12-14 16:17:21*

And this is my program logic. I want to check if 72 hours passed **else** echo you need to wait 48 hours and 22 minutes and 55seconds for example.

```
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
$last_dl = $row['last_dl'];

// To seconds from 1970
$last_dl = strtotime($last_dl); //120
$seventy_two_hours_in_seconds = 60 * 60 * 72;

if (time() > ($last_dl + $seventy_two_hours_in_seconds)) {
    echo "72 Passed";
} else {
    echo "You need to wait: " . date('H/h i/m s/s',mktime(0, 0, ($last_dl + $seventy_two_hours_in_seconds) - time()));
}
```

What is wrong with the logic. Cause it shows way less hours.

Comment: Using [`DATE_ADD()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) might help you if you are using MySQL

Comment: date_default_timezone_set()

Comment: @MrKen Nope. That didn't work.

Comment: I run it and it working normal, using `print_r($row)` to view result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate time in second to wait, and after present it in hours, minutes and seconds:

```
<?php
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
$last_dl = $row['last_dl'];

// To seconds from 1970
$last_dl = strtotime($last_dl); //120
$seventy_two_hours_in_seconds = 60 * 60 * 72;

if (time() > ($last_dl + $seventy_two_hours_in_seconds)) {
    echo "72 Passed";
} else {
    $wait = date('U', $last_dl + $seventy_two_hours_in_seconds) - date('U'); // seconds for wait
    $hours = floor($wait /3600);
    $min = floor(($wait / 60) % 60);
    $sec = $wait % 60;
    echo "You need to wait: ". $hours. ':'. $min.':'.$sec ."\n";
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08477cd78c82dfe2b4a5c5f4aee6414866999a8c